# MapReduce context output in Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop

I am having a problem running any MR job written in scala on my CDH 4.2 distribution. This line

context.write(...)

causes Error: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext, but class was expected
no problem in java. Can anyone help? Here is the full example:

```
class MyMapper extends Mapper[Object,Text,Text,IntWritable] {
    val one = new IntWritable(1)
    val word = new Text

    override def map(key:Object, value:Text, context:Mapper[Object,Text,Text,IntWritable]#Context)  {
        context.write(word, one)
    }
}

object WordCount {

    def main(args:Array[String]):Int = {
        val conf = new Configuration()
        val job = new Job(conf, "word count")

        job.setJarByClass(classOf[MyMapper])
        job.setMapperClass(classOf[MyMapper])
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0)
        job.setOutputKeyClass(classOf[Text])
        job.setOutputValueClass(classOf[IntWritable])
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args(0)))
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path((args(1))))
        if (job.waitForCompletion(true)) 0 else 1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before.  My guess is that you compiled your jar with references to an older/different version of Hadoop where `TaskInputOutputContext` was is class, but your cluster version has changed it to be an interface.  You can avoid significant amounts of unneeded pain if you compile to the same version of Hadoop that your cluster is running.